# Socket io Nodejs- manage when a user open multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel-5, redis, socket.io

I am trying to write a chat in my app, I have an issue that have no idea how to manage it!
Here is the senario:
We have lot's of users that are authenricated so all of them have a unique id, I want to implement a chat like Facebook so every two users can chat with each other.
For that I have a server.js file with content:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('redis');
var users = [];
server.listen(8890);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log("client connected");
    var redisClient = redis.
    redisClient.subscribe('message');

    redisClient.on("message", function(channel, data) {
        var data = JSON.parse(data);
        socket.to('user_'+data.user).emit(channel, data);
    });

    // join a room    
    socket.on('newUser',function (user, type){
        socket.type = type;
        socket.join('user_'+user); 

    }); 
});
```

And a client.js:

```
var socket = io.connect( 'http://127.0.0.1:8890' );
if (auth) {
    socket.on('connect', function(){
        socket.emit('newUser', userId, userType);
    });
}

socket.on( 'message', function( data ) {

    console.log(data);
    // var data = JSON.parse(data);
    var content = $( "#messages" ).html();
    var newMsgContent = '<li>' + data.message + '</li>';
    var newContent = newMsgContent + content;

    $( "#messages" ).html( newContent );
});
```

A form that message will be sent with:

```
<form action="{{ route('message.send') }}" method="POST" class="ajax-form">
    <input name="_method" value="put" type="hidden"/>
    <input name="user" value="{{ $user }}" type="hidden"/>
    <input name="item" value="{{ $item }}" type="hidden"/>
    <input name="type" value="{{ $type }}" type="hidden"/>
    <input name="socketId" value="" type="hidden"/>
    <input name="message" value="message to {{ $user }} from {{ @$requirements->user->id }}" type="text" class="input-xxlarge" placeHolder="Message" />
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

And at last with Redis I will send the message:

```
$redis = \LRedis::connection();
$data = ['user' => $request->user, 'message' => $request->message];
if($redis->publish('message', json_encode($data)))
   return true;
```

In above codes simply when a user open my app a connection will be used and newUser will fire up so I create a room for this user with his Id and join him to this room (socket.join('user_'+user)). 
Then when a user want to send a message to this user simply I send id of receiver user (that we created a room before for him) and send the message to the room that this Id is in it (socket.to('user_'+data.user).emit(channel, data);). 
The problem is that when a user open multiple tabs each one of them recognized as a user and will join to the same room with another socket.id  but both are a user with one unique Id!
Then when I send a message to a user that has two tabs open, he will get 2 messages from one request! like:
Hello id 5
Hello id 5

So now what should I do to sent message per tab to all tabs that user  opened! 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Really I don't even know what that means I am really new in node.js and socket.io. @MarcosCasagrande

Comment: Yes I guess... @MarcosCasagrande

Comment: Put a console log in your ` redisClient.on("message", function(channel, data) {` and see if it is triggered twice, since I tested your code without redis and works.

Comment: Yes it works fine without redis! but why!! Is this redis problem? @MarcosCasagrande

Comment: I am sure it doesn't fire twice! actually sometimes it is base one tab numbers if I open 4 tabs in chrome and one tab in firefox and send a message from firefox fo chrome, chrome will receive 4 message in one request!

Comment: Check my answer, let me know if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `redisCLient.subscribe` outside of the connection listener. Every time a connection is made, you attach the event again, that's why you're getting duplicates.

```
var redisClient = redis.createClient();
redisClient.subscribe('message');

redisClient.on("message", function(channel, data) {
  var data = JSON.parse(data);
  //Changed socket.to with io.to
  io.to('user_'+ data.user).emit(channel, data);
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log("client connected");

    // join a room    
    socket.on('newUser',function (user, type){
        socket.type = type;
        socket.join('user_'+user); 

    }); 
});
```

As a side note, your client code can be improved using [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
socket.on( 'message', function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
    // var data = JSON.parse(data);
    $( "#messages" ).append('<li>' + data.message + '</li>');    
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I put a console.log on message redis client but notting happend no log!

Comment: @HassanShojaei you have something wrong then, because just moving the redis message listener from outside the socket connection shouldn't break the code, since redis has nothing to do with socketio.

Comment: Yes I got the typo, with that server didn't even start... but still it doesn't work out on io.on('connection'...!

Comment: also the two first lines should be like this I guess:
var redisClient = redis.createClient();
    redisClient.subscribe('message');

Comment: It is not possible that the redis listener is not being fired, I need to check the full code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142538/discussion-between-marcos-casagrande-and-hassan-shojaei).